# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean passing in Wordpress ACF Datepicker to template

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my code:

```
$original_date = get_field('event_date');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('lFdY', strtotime($original_date));
$new_date = $date->format('l, F d, Y');
```

This code is in a custom post loop in a shortcode and called in the Wordpress admin.

I have also tried it without the `strtotime`.  I am using PHP 5.6. 
The `event_date` field is from an Advance Custom Fields date picker.

If I just pass the field, I get my intended output (the input from the custom post admin page), but without whitespace and commas.  I also set this, save and display values in the acf in WP.

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean on the line
>   with $new_date variable.

Then if I use:

```
$date = date("l, F d, Y", strtotime($original_date));
```

The loop throws an error, undefined variable, for each instance of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jbafford I found a solution.
First I save the date format to yymmdd in the ACF datepicker field

Then I used this code to extract the year month and date separately and then formatted the strtotime result:

```
$odate = get_field('event_date');
$y = substr($odate, 0, 4); $m = substr($odate, 4, 2); $d = substr($odate, 6, 2);

$new_date = date('l, F j, Y', strtotime("{$d}-{$m}-{$y}"));
```

What confused me I think and got me hung up was the presumption that I had to pass l or the day into the strtotime and that I had to match input with the intended formatted output.  PHP date doesn't need that much info to accomplish the task.  Thanks for all of your input!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the string directly to the `createFromFormat` method:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('lFdY', $original_date);
```

The `boolean` you're receiving is because `createFromFormat` is failing and returning `false`.

If you're still receiving an error, `get_field()` is likely not returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) returns `false` if it fails to convert the input string using the format specified.

In your case, you're taking an `$original_date`, converting it to a numeric timestamp, and trying to pass that in to `DateTime::createFromFormat`, which isn't going to work, hence the error. You'll need to pass in the original date instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('lFdY', $original_date);
```

PHP currently can not parse that specific format string. You can demonstrate this with an easy case that should "obviously" work. This:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('lFdY', date('lFdY', time()));
```

returns `false`. The issue is specifically because of the lack of space between `l` and `F` in the format string and between the day-of-week and month in your input string.

You should use a different date format. If you can remove the text representation of the day-of-week (because it's not actually necessary to disambiguate the date), or at least get a space between the day-of-week and the month, that would be best.

Since you have existing data in your database in an unhelpful format, you could write a relatively simple pre-processor to remove the day-of-week from the input string:

```
$new_date = substr($original_date, strpos($original_date, 'y') + 1);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('FdY', $new_date);
```

(This example assumes always english day names, in lowercase, and the input is always valid. You may need more complicated code for your actual data.)

**Nitty, gritty details:** When PHP [processes][2] the `l` formatter (day of week), it requires seeing one of the characters in: `,;:/.-()`, a space, tab, or end-of-string as an indication of where to stop reading.

So, if your date string is `FridayJuly082016`, because there are no spaces whatsoever in the input date, the code continues reading the *entire* string, and then fails because (literally) `FridayJuly082016` is not in the list of days of the week.

Unfortunately for your particular case, this is also not likely to be "fixed". You have an extremely unusual date format, and making this particular case work in the code would make it considerably more complicated, for a questionable and rare use case.

Comment: and @rnevius  
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('lFdY', $original_date);
    $new_date = $date->format('l, F d, Y');  
still returns with the same boolean error

Comment: @ardev What is the `$original_date` you are trying to use?

Comment: the ' $original_date = get_field('event_date');'
That is the field name of my ACF datepicker field.  

When I simply echo '$original_date' I get the input for each custom post type, but without the formatting, the formatting which I also set in the ACF configuration.

Comment: Yes, but, what is the actual *value*? If the date doesn't actually match the format you specified, it's not going to work.

Comment: Oh ok, well since its a loop, its varies for each individual custom post type item, of course.  This is what is return when I echo '$original_date' :
FridayJuly082016SundayFebruary072016MondayFebruary012016              
That is what I would expect, except the whitespace and the commas are stripped.  Hence the attempt to format it, of course

Comment: @ardev See edit. Looking into it further, but the problem is that PHP actually can't parse the date string when there's no space between the textual day-of-week and textual month, and you're going to have to change your code one way or another for it to work.

Comment: @ardev Updated the answer with the full why, and an option for what you can do about it. But basically, don't use `lFdY`, because PHP won't, and probably never will, support parsing that.

Comment: great description..thanks for going into depth on that.  I found a solution that is passing the correct dates into the template.  I posted it here as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using this .. `<?php echo date('l, F d, Y', strtotime(get_field('event_date')));?>` it is working at my end

> Make sure your `get_field('event_date')` returns you the date in **20160113** `format` If not then change the return format from ACF setting in WP back-end.

[image]

Comment: Using that line of code returns Unix Start time: Thursday, January 01, 1970

When I just echo $original_date as 
        $original_date = get_field('event_date');

Comment: Using that line of code  
        $new_date = date("l, F d, Y", strtotime(get_field('event_date')));  
 returns Unix Start time: Thursday, January 01, 1970  
  
When I just echo $original_date as   
        $original_date = get_field('event_date');  
I get the intended date, FridayJuly082016 without the formatting I'm looking for.  
  
seems the date method is replacing the input  
  
My save format is DDmmddyy and my display format is DD, MM dd, yy
what is your ACF version? I have 4.4.5 but I dont have radio buttons for choosing display and save (not Return like yours), just an input field.

Comment: Ok in that case you should try updating the version of acf.. please first exports all the custom field created in current acf and moreover take a backup of database also for safe side if importing the acf xml doesn't works

Comment: my installed version, 4.4.5, is the latest version.